# MySQL 5.1 InnoDB file-per-table option

Tags: mysql, innodb

My application uses MySQL 5.1.49 as its main DB.
The default table engine for my version of MySQL is MyISAM, but since I want to use InnoDB (which is the default engine for version 5.5 and higher), I have to specify the following line in the end of each `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_bin';
```

I need to save a specific table in a different location within the file system. I turned on the file-per-table option, and added the `DATA DIRECTORY` flag.
MySQL ignores the `DATA DIRECTORY` flag when the active engine is InnoDB.

If I remove the InnoDB statement (thus forcing it to work with the default engine, MyISAM), it works, but then I lose all the advantages of the InnoDB engine.

Is there a way to combine them both WITHOUT upgrading to MySQL 5.5?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the `DATA DIRECTORY` option is not supported for InnoDB until MySQL 5.6. The only way to achieve what you want would be to use symlinks at the filesystem level, but this is very dangerous and not recommended.

Comment: We really did end up using symlinks, but that solution was scrapped as well later on. Thanks anyway :-)